# nodejs convert wav, mp3 to AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, wav

I have **wav** file and i went to convert to AudioBuffer because i have some function that only take audio buffer as input how can i get audio buffer from audio file? i've already searched the internet and all i got was converting from audio buffer to wav not what i wanted, and i try to feed the function with Base64 data of the audio, no luck

i've already write this function but it look like it doesn't gives me what i wanted

```
const getbuffer = async (url) => {
    try {
        var result =  await axios
            .get(url, {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            })
            .then(response =>  new Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'))
            return result
    }catch (e) {
        return {error: e};
    }
}
```

the buffer i want is to feed to this function so it can change the audio for me

```
async function alienSoundTransform(audioBuffer) {

  let ctx = offlineContext(audioBuffer.numberOfChannels, audioBuffer.length, audioBuffer.sampleRate);

  let source = ctx.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = audioBuffer;

  let oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = 5;
  oscillator.type = 'sine';

  let oscillatorGain = ctx.createGain();
  oscillatorGain.gain.value = 0.05;

  let delay = ctx.createDelay();
  delay.delayTime.value = 0.05;

  // source --> delay --> ctx.destination
  // oscillator --> oscillatorGain --> delay.delayTime --> ctx.destination

  source.connect(delay);
  delay.connect(ctx.destination);

  oscillator.connect(oscillatorGain);
  oscillatorGain.connect(delay.delayTime);

  oscillator.start();
  source.start();

  let outputAudioBuffer = await ctx.startRendering();
  return outputAudioBuffer;

}
```

Comment: need more details. It depends on the consumer of that buffer that you need to make out of wav file

Comment: @AlexShchur edited the question have a look at it please